# use edit widget to create optional picklist for a field in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to set up a field to select from a picklist using the Value Relation or Value Map edit widget on a shapefile field in QGIS so that one will be able to pick from a list of items but not necessarily be restricted/constrained to using one of the items in the list (i.e., one can also enter an item/string that is not present in the picklist)?

The purpose is to provide users with a list of items to jog their memory when entering the data; however, I have no need or desire to constrain their entry.

Comment: I tried this and the only way I could figure out was to edit the data in the field calculator using an expression.  However, the text was surrounded by "( )"  indicating that the value wasn't part of the Value Map.

Comment: That is an Interesting way to override the dropdown list. if you create a 2nd  layer style that does not have the picklist (valuemap) then you can enter values not in the list and the () will disappear